# counting number of lines in file

Tags: c

I have written a c code to count the number of characters , number of digits,and number of lines in a file. unfortunately the number of lines is not giving the exact count.I have written the below code .

```
#include<stdio.h>

void scan();
FILE *fp;

int numbercount=0,textcount=0,spacecount=0,newlinecount=0,specialcount=0;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

 if(argc<2)
 {
     printf("\n Enter the filename through the command line ! ");
 }
 else
 {
    fp=fopen( argv[1],"r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    printf("\n Cannot Open the file ");
   else 
    scan();  
 }
}


void scan()
{

char ch;
while(1)
{
   ch=fgetc(fp);
   if((ch>=65 && ch<=90)||(ch>=97 && ch<=122))
   {
      textcount++;
   }

   else if(ch>=48&&ch<=57)
   {
       numbercount++;
   }

  else if(ch==','||ch=='!'||ch=='?'||ch=='.')
   {
       specialcount++;
   }
   else if(ch==' ')
   {
       spacecount++;

   }
   else if(ch=='\n')
   {
       newlinecount++;

   }
   else if(ch==EOF)
   break;
}

   printf("\n The count of charecters  in the text = %d ",textcount);
   printf("\n The count of numbers in the text = %d ",numbercount);
   printf("\n The count of special charecters in the text = %d",specialcount);
   printf("\n The count of newlines  = %d ",newlinecount);
   printf("\n The number of spaces   = %d \n",spacecount);

 }
```

I have given the input text file content as below http://pastebin.com/GXVdqfzT , the code gives the line count as 6 instead of 11. Is there an appropriate way to calculate the line count.

Comment: ...the file seems to have a linecount of 6, as indicated in the pastebin. Am I missing something?

Comment: There's a difference between a wrap and a newline feed. When you run out of space but keep typing you wrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the no. of lines were 11, a text editor will show 11 as the final line number. It says 6 which means the words flow on the next line because of word wrapping. Copy paste it into notepad without word wrap and you will see.

There is no character in the lines which causes the words to be wrapped onto the next line (unlike `\n` which is stored and causes a newline). Word wrap is a feature of the editor not something that depends on the data (characters in the line)(it makes check if the line is exceeding the current width of the editor window and makes a wrap.)

Answer (score 4):

When in doubt on your input look at the data in the raw with an octal or hex dump program... one that shows readable Ascii as well.  You could then see the actual lines.

Also, opening even text files in binary can sometimes help sort out odd behavior.

BUG ALERT: what happens if the last line does not have a line ending character? It happens.

Answer (score 2):

The file does have 6 lines, they're are just wrapped and seem like 11.